# display the length of the first word of a dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I'm having problems trying to switch the output of the FirstWordLength to print the amount of characters in each first word  this output to

```
 SELECT InvoiceLineItemDescription,
LEFT(InvoiceLineItemDescription, 
 CASE 
 WHEN charindex(' ', InvoiceLineItemDescription) = 0 THEN LEN(InvoiceLineItemDescription) 
 ELSE charindex(' ', InvoiceLineItemDescription) - 1 END)
 AS FirstWordLength
 FROM InvoiceLineItems
 ORDER BY FirstWordLength desc;
```

It should look something like this:

```
InvoiceLineItemDescription     FirstWordLength
citi bank                          4
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the first word length using `charindex()`:

```
SELECT InvoiceLineItemDescription,
       CHARINDEX(' ', InvoiceLineItemDescription + ' ') - 1 as FirstWordLength
FROM InvoiceLineItems
ORDER BY FirstWordLength desc;
```

As in your question, this assumes that only spaces are used for delimiting words.  You can use `PATINDEX()` to support more separator characters.

The `case` in your code should work, but you are using it to extract the first word, rather than just the length.